# Shadows and Reflections

Tags: shaders, lighting, shadows, world, emission

I am trying to make this[image]

But I am stuck on this image
[image]
None of my walls or other materials are picking up the white emission and the back of the corridor is getting light from somewhere. Any ideas in terms of lighting and shadows? I have screen space reflections and ambient occlusion on, and am running filmic. It seems like only the normals/height sections of my walls are picking up light. Not sure what I have set wrong or what I don't have set at all.

Comment: maybe it's coming from the world? Try to put its color to 100% black

Comment: could you provide your blend file, so we could have a look?

Comment: I think I figured it out. I basically cheated by putting point lights in the emissive surface and its looking correct. I also did put the world color to complete black which helped with the shadows. I guess my questions is, does an emissive surface generate actual light in any way? Or is it just for show and you have to add an external light in there to make it look real?

Comment: They do but emission seems quite weak.  The scale of the scene might affect it